# iterator that reads values from file

Tags: python, io, iterator, with-statement

Is it possible to read values from a file with an iterator, so that the file is automatically closed at the end of the iteration?

Creating such an iterator using the `with` statement doesn't seem to work.

```
with open('/dev/zero', 'rb') as f:                                              
    values = iter(f.read(1) for i in (1, 2, 3))                                 

values.next()             #ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

Comment: You'll need to create a wrapper class, implement `__iter__` and `__next__`, and call `f.__exit__()` when you raise a `StopIteration`.

Comment: What you try to do isn't advisable because if you forget to iterate to the end or an exception happens you'll leak a file handle.All operations on a file should be done inside the `with`!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use `with` you need to do:

```
def file_generator(filename):
    with open(filename,'rb') as file:
        for i in (1, 2, 3):
            yield file.read(1)

values = file_generator('/dev/zero')
next(values)
```

However if you don't reach the end of this iterator, you will never close the file, so in essence it's not very different from:

```
file = open(filename,'rb')
next(file)
file.close()
```

When processing a file it's best to go through it all at once if you can, and then close it once you are done using it. Keeping a handle on an open file is usually not a reliable solution.

Comment: Don't do that in production code. This can easily leak a file handle when the generator isn't exhausted or the generator isn't deleted if an exception happened. (Almost all the good points of `with` are negated if you use `yield` inside the context).

Comment: @MSeifert I agree yes. However OP wants to have an iterator on a file, so either you keep the file open between two calls to next, or you close it and re-open it every time, but I don't see any satisfying solution. All in all, most of the time it's best to process the file all at once and then close it or implement a special handle for custom usage.

Comment: @MSeifert as long as you make sure `.close()` is called there should be no leaks, right?

Comment: Yeah, but the `with` is essentially useless then - because if you need to make sure you call `.close()` yourself, then what's the point of using `with`?

Answer (score 1):

The [fileinput](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html) module does that for you. Opening and closing files is handled automatically.

```
import fileinput

files = ['path to file']

iterator = fileinput.input(files)

for line in iterator:
    print(line)
```

You can give a list of multiple file paths to the `input` method and it will iterate over their lines like it was reading a single file.

Comment: Thanks. I think the standard `file` object already allows you to iterate over lines. The problem is when you want to iterate over bits of data that aren't lines or that are not sequential.